# IOS Swift User Location Authorization

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cllocationmanager

I have an app that is tracking a User's location. I have much experience with this and have requested when in use Authorization and have added the key to my P-List, however I still receive this error:

> "Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for
>   location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager
>   requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager
>   requestAlwaysAuthorization] first."

The location Manager that I am using is not in the `ViewController` but in another class.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where those methods are called from, so you could call either of those methods either from your app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method (these authorization methods run asynchronously) or in the `viewDidAppear` method of your very first view controller.

Comment: I am calling it from a operate custom class, and I figured as much. I can't determine why I still get the error message when I clearly do request user authorization.

Comment: try setting a breakpoint (or use `print` or `NSLog`) to determine which gets called first... your authorization methods or the MapKit methods which are causing these error messages to fire.

Answer (score 0):

check the [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] before setting mapView.showsUserLocation = YES or startUpdatingLocation
Make sure that your CLLocation variable is strong.

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) //or kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways
   {
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

You must use anyone of the authorization

```
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization(); or self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
```

Anyhow the warning will not come for the second time after the user accept the permission

Comment: I have tried commenting out the "map view.showUserLocaton" and I get the same result however without the error. Still the app never asks for authorization.

Comment: Which version of iOS you are using ?. Can you please paste some of your code snippets

Comment: Excuse me for I have forgotten how to format my code on stack over flow.

Comment: I have implemented the delegates, the app does not even ask the user for permission

Comment: the warning/error will not come for the second time after the user accept the    permission

Comment: @loadedjd try the apple sample https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html  its not giving error unless we call         self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
before authorization. just compare your code with the apple sample